# Tkinter now allowing me to print all the data that i would like

Tags: python, tkinter

i would like it to print all of the planets in the class like it does when I print it but it only prints the last one I have tried a few things but none have worked I would like it to print each planet under one another

```
def infomation(day_count, planets):
    Day.config(text=day_count)
    for planet in planets:
        Infomation.config(text='{:<8} posision (m)  x ={:6.2f}  y ={:6.2f} velocity (m/s)  x ={:9.2f}  y = {:9.2f} '.format(
                planet.planet_name, planet.pos_x/AU, planet.pos_y/AU, planet.velocity_x, planet.velocity_y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to store the formatted string for each planet and then join those strings and display the joined string in `Infomation`:

```py
def infomation(day_count, planets):
    Day.config(text=day_count)
    txt = []
    for planet in planets:
        txt.append('{:<8} posision (m)  x ={:6.2f}  y ={:6.2f} velocity (m/s)  x ={:9.2f}  y = {:9.2f} '.format(
                planet.planet_name, planet.pos_x/AU, planet.pos_y/AU, planet.velocity_x, planet.velocity_y))
    Infomation.config(text='\n'.join(txt))
```

Comment: I'd say tho that for some pretty complex string like this one, using `f strings` would be a way better approach